# Lesser contents/elements in a wp-page once smaller than a specific size in width

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, element, custom-wordpress-pages

As the title suggests, I'm looking to have the home page of a responsive WordPress design with lesser content. This is as the home page is very long, content wise and that makes it out of human tolerance to get to the bottom of the page on a mobile device.

So the question is how to have the page with lesser content once the width becomes less than let's say 480px? Does it work by defining two homes pages in Wordpress? how to tell which to load & when? or is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve it like this:

- wrap the content that you'd like to make disappear in a  or  with a unique class name say:

  `<div class="mr-class-name"> 
  My content that I would like to make disappear when the viewport is anything less than 481px
  </div>`
- then using a media query at the bottom of your CSS file you could say:

  @media all and (max-width:480px)
  {
      .mr-class-name { display: none; }
  }

That should do it.